# Is it possible or not to use a native php function in Twig?

Tags: php, function, templates, symfony, twig

I am a newbie on Symfony. How can I use a native php function in a twig template?

For example I want to use the function `chr` in a loop like this:

```
{% for directory in directories %}
    chr(loop.index)
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should edit your title to say `in Twig` instead of `in Symfony 2`.

Comment: and why whoudl you want to convert the `loop.index` to its ascii character???

Comment: It's a exemple, I just want to know if it is possible or not ? ;)

Answer (score 8):

Twig allows you to add [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions) and [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters). There're multiple examples on [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html).

**For example,**

- [Creating a filter is as simple as associating a name with a PHP
  callable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters)

Comment: I know, but I want to use native function, must I redeclare them as twig functions ? I just want to know if it is possible or not ? ;)

Comment: @user777897: As far as i know, yes. Thats part of the point is that one should be limited to the facilities provided by the template engine

Comment: Yes, better is to handle it this way. Twig can be easily extended, adding functions and filters is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use PHP directly in Twig.

There are some options:

### Use PHP as the templating engine

You can set PHP as the templating engine instead of twig. This means you use PHP inside your templates and you can use all native PHP functions. See [this doc article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html) on how to do that.

### Create a Twig extension

You could easilly create your own Twig extension. The best practise is to create a `AcmeTwigBundle` where you put all those common Twig extensions. See [this doc article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) on how to do that in Symfony.

As of Twig 1.12 (Symfony2.2 comes with it), there is a really nice class which allows you to easilly map a PHP function to a twig function:

```php
new Twig_SimpleFilter('rot13', 'str_rot13');
```

This will create a `rot13` Twig function which maps to the `str_rot13` PHP function.